# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" - Java

Tags: java, swing, variables, exception

when I try to run this program the following error message appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Quiz1.<init>(Quiz1.java:21)
at Opening_Screen.jButton1ActionPerformed(Opening_Screen.java:138)
at Opening_Screen.access$000(Opening_Screen.java:16)
at Opening_Screen$1.actionPerformed(Opening_Screen.java:57)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

As I'm extremely new to Java I have absolutely no idea what any of this means, if someone could show me where in my code this is happening I'd be extremely appreciative!

Here is the code.

```
public class Quiz1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList <String> quiz1Answers = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> quiz1UserAnswers = new ArrayList();

String q1 = this.txtInputQ1.getText();
String q2 = this.txtInputQ2.getText();
String q3 = this.txtInputQ3.getText();
String q4 = this.txtInputQ4.getText();
String q5 = this.txtInputQ5.getText();
String q6 = this.txtInputQ6.getText();
String q7 = this.txtInputQ7.getText();
String q8 = this.txtInputQ8.getText();

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a practice quize to test what you have learned.", "Instructions", +  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>To check your answers press the <b><i>'Check'</b></i> button and enter which question to check", "Instructions", +  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>When completed click the <b><i>'Start Quiz'</b></i> button", "Instructions", +  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}                                        

private void txtInputQ6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (q1.equals("") || q2.equals("") || q3.equals("") || q4.equals("") || q5.equals("") || q6.equals("") || q7.equals("") || q8.equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Make sure all fields are filled in!", "Error!", +  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else
    {
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q1);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q2);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q3);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q4);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q5);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q6);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q7);
        quiz1UserAnswers.add(q8);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Press the <b><i>'Check Answer'</b></i> button now!", "", +  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Collections.addAll(quiz1Answers, "ottawa", "toronto", "tokyo", "northamerica", "seoul", "Asia", "unitedstates", "50");

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google for Null Pointer Exception. Or rather, search on this site for it. The problem lies here `String q1 = this.txtInputQ1.getText();` You are trying to use the `this` keyword before an object is created. In fact, I don't see where you create any of the `txtInputQ1`, `txtInputQ2`, etc... The only objects you have created are the 2 ArrayLists.

Comment: @Takendarkk Will do! Ah, dumb mistake on my part. Anyways thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Sure thing. If you do some research and still have problems you can edit your question or open a new one.

Comment: Important thing to note is that you should be using `List<String> quiz1Answers = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably going to assume that you're trying to get the values before even **initializing** the object. Make sure that the object `txtInputQ1` till `txtInputQ2` is first created before you call the `.getText();` method.